# Can we see refraction of light in the air with our eyes?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, perception

Can we see refraction of light in the air with our eyes?
I am asking that because every night I see that the light in the street moving little is that because of change in the air?

I do not mean Street light interference.

Comment: Yeah we can.  Heat waves off of a hot surface or mirages off of a road in the distance are due to refraction of light in the air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, that is what the wavy motion over a hot car is, and also the cause of mirror-like mirages on deserts and hot roads. Stars also twinkle due to the same effect. Not sure about street lights per se, but I'm sure there are combinations where air refraction of light would show up there also.

Answer (score 2):

Another interesting way to see this, if you live or work where you can see a mountain range, is to train a telescope to some object on top of the mountain. Not only will you see the quivverring image you speak of, if your telescope mounts are stable and you don't adjust them, you will see that the object will move up and down in the telescope from day to day as the refractive index profile, and thus the "effective" Earth curvature (see [the Wikipedia Article on Anomalous Propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_propagation). Indeed, if the mountain range is far enough away, the object will shift right out of the field of view on some days. About 80km from where I live, there is a mountain range. Some days it looks distant and you can only just see the peaks. Other days it looks huge and you can see the bottoms of the mountains. I live in an area that has many atmospheric [temperature inversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_inversion).

Comment: This is the reason why it is surprisingly hard to know how tall a mountain is... ordinary optical surveying techniques fail over the kinds of distances involved.

Comment: @Floris Yes, I've often wondered how Gauss accounted for this when he was looking for deviations from the Euclidean axioms in the geometry of physical space. He looked at extensive surveying records and probably dabbled himself. He would have been absolutely aware of this effect and he got the precision and accuracy down to seconds of arc in his assertion that the World did not experimentally deviate from Euclid's parallel axiom (the sums of surveyed triangles added up to 180 degrees to within this margin). Also how the French came up with the meter as 1/10000 of the distance along the ....

Comment: ... Earth along the meridian through a certain point. They would have needed to account for this.